# Oracle date compare( invalid identifier)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, ora-00904

I have this query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(HON.CREATE_DT,'DD-MM-YYYY') as CREATE_DT, 
       HON.ACCOUNT_NO,(SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL) AS NV
              FROM medium.HONSCRIBERS HON, 
                   medium.HONSCRIBER_TEXT pcode, 
                   medium.ACCESS_NUMBERS accnr
              WHERE 
                accnr.STATUS_CD = 'CU' AND
                pcode.TRADING_AS ='7777777'AND
                HON.ACCOUNT_NO=pcode.ACCOUNT_NO AND
                HON.ACCOUNT_NO=accnr.ACCOUNT_NO
```

It returns :

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [CREATE_DT] => 28-02-2008
            [ACCOUNT_NO] => 20340322
            [NV] => 20-05-2011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CREATE_DT] => 28-02-2008
            [ACCOUNT_NO] => 20340322
            [NV] => 20-05-2011
        )
```

I need to compare dates CREATE_DT AND NV
My query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(HON.CREATE_DT,'DD-MM-YYYY') as CREATE_DT, 
       HON.ACCOUNT_NO,(SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL) AS NV
              FROM medium.HONSCRIBERS HON, 
                   medium.HONSCRIBER_TEXT pcode, 
                   medium.ACCESS_NUMBERS accnr
              WHERE 
                accnr.STATUS_CD = 'CU' AND          CREATE_DT < NV AND
                pcode.TRADING_AS ='7777777'AND
                HON.ACCOUNT_NO=pcode.ACCOUNT_NO AND
                HON.ACCOUNT_NO=accnr.ACCOUNT_NO
```

I have this error:

```
[code] => 904
 [message] => ORA-00904: "NV": invalid identifier
 [offset] => 325
```

Why he always wrote me :  "NV": invalid identifier? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a column alias in the WHERE clause of the same query.  You have to repeat the expression it is an alias for:

```
AND CREATE_DT < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY)
```

(Note you don't want the TO_CHAR here otherwise the comparison will not work correctly)